# Sharepoint List validation with text and Number

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to figure out a validation for one of my Sharepoint online list column.

One of my column should start with the text "M" then followed by 9 numbers EG: M000010854. Is it possible to have a validation like that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the formula below, it shall work for you.

```
=AND((LEFT(<columnName>,1)="M"),(LEN(<columnName>)=10))
```